# ratchet websocket connection failed on VPS

Tags: php, websocket, real-time, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I try to write ratchet chat webAplication. it works well on xampp but it doesn't work on server. I run server.php from ssh and get this error when open the site:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://farahaniacademy.com:8080/' failed.

here is my code:

server.php:

```
<?php 

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );


    $server->run();
?>
```

index.php:

```
<script>
const conn = new WebSocket('ws://farahaniacademy.com:8080');
        conn.onopen = function(e)
        {
            console.log("Connection established!");
        };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved. the problem was the firewall of server. when I allow the port everything works fine.